# cant export token to another file in cypress

Tags: arrays, typescript, cypress, cypress-component-test-runner

i make an api request to get the token and use it in another function in a seprate file, when i export the token from one file to another it is not working as expected , the activat user method can not read the token

my code in one file

```
class User {

  user_T= ''

  getaccessToken(){

    cy.request({

        method: 'POST',
        url: 'url',
        form: true,
        body: {
          
          "username": .,..
          "password": ....
  
        }
      })
      .then( response=> {
         
          return this.user_T= response.body.Token;
      })
  }
}

export default new User
```

the other file is

```
import User from './user'

const token= new User()


it.only('activate user', () => {
  
    cy.request({
      
      method: "POST",
      url: 'url/activate',
      headers: {
        'Authorization' : 'Bearer ' + token.user_T,
      
    },
      body:{
       "test": 'test'
      } 
    }) 
   
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You do not need to return `this.user_T= response.body.Token;` in your `.then()` block. If you are setting the value of `this.user_T`, then you can just do that. If you want to return the value of `response.body.Token` so that you can assign it a value, you can just do that. But doing both, while not causing any issues with how you are using it currently, is not the correct way.

```js
.then((response) => {
  this.user_T = response.access.Token
});
// or
.then((response) => {
  return response.access.Token
});
```

If you are returning the value from the `.then()`, you'll also have to return the entire `cy.request()` command chain.

2. `getaccessToken` is the function that actually generates a non-empty string value for `user_T`. In order to have `user_T` not equal an empty string, you'll need to call that function.

```
// Assuming you are still setting the `user_T` value instead of returning it
import User from './user'

const user = new User()

it.only('activate user', () => {
  user.getaccessToken().then(() => {
    cy.request({
      
      method: "POST",
      url: 'url/activate',
      headers: {
        'Authorization' : 'Bearer ' + user.user_T,
    },
      body:{
       "test": 'test'
      } 
    }) 
  })
})
```

Comment: i get this error ```This expression is not constructable.
  Type 'User' has no construct signatures.``` for the line const user= new User(

Comment: Try just using `const user = User`